# How does javac calculate public static final int NaN = 0 / 0?

Tags: java

I wonder how javac calculates this constant expression?

```
class Test {
   public static final int NaN = 0 / 0;
...
```

Comment: This will throw `ArithmeticException-DivideByZero`.

Comment: I notice that you are asking an awful lot of questions like this one. May I suggest that you would be better off just *trying it out*, or *reading the JLS* ... especially as (it would seem) you are merely asking these questions out of idle curiosity.

Comment: Right, the next one I wanted to ask was what happens when we cast NaN to long

Comment: It doesn't. Not a real question.

Comment: `what happens when we cast NaN to long ` I suggest you try it, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

It's defined in the [Java Language Specification, §15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2):

> There is one special case that does not satisfy this rule: if the dividend is the negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type, and the divisor is -1, then integer overflow occurs and the result is equal to the dividend. Despite the overflow, no exception is thrown in this case. On the other hand, if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an `ArithmeticException` is thrown.

What that means:  If the dividend is 0, it really doesn't matter what the divisor is; it'll throw `ArithmeticException` outright.

Now, if you were using *doubles*, that would give you back `NaN` by [JLS §15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2).

Answer (score 0):

There is no representation for 'NaN' or 'Inf' values in Java's integer primitive types.  (Or in most other languages for that matter.)

What actually happens is that an `ArithmeticException` will be thrown ... at runtime.

Since this expression is evaluated in the static initialization of a class, the initialization class will fail and any other classes that depend on it will also fail initialization.  There is a good chance that your application won't even make it to the first statement of the `main` method.